# Notepad++ Installation Error: Installation of plugin failed

Tags: installation, notepad++, plugins

I installed the newest version of Notepad++ on my Win 8.1 Professional. The version is called "Notepad++ Je suis Charlie edition, Build Time Jan 10 2015 - 17:20:21". The Plugin Manager delivered with that version of Notepad++ is 1.0.8. Now I want to add the "Compare" plugin:

- I start plugin manager.
- I wait until the list of available plugins has built up.
- I check "Compare" and click "Install".
- "An update is available to plugin Manager. It is *strongly* recommended..." -> "Yes".
- "Installation Error: Installation of Plugin Manager failed."
- "OK", and "Install" again.
- "An update is available to plugin Manager. It is *strongly* recommended..." -> "No".
- "Installation Error: Installation of Compare failed."

What exactly am I doing wrong? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: I just ran into this error, and the fix for me was: update my copy of explorer++ to the latest version.

Comment: Sad that this problem still exists in 2019. None of the solutions solved it for me. I attempted on two different machines. I can only conclude the plugin manager is not useful.

Answer (score 23):

#### Error: Installation of plugin failed

The latest version of the plugin manager was 1.4.9 at the time this answer was written(see [Notepad++ Plugin Manager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager))

You can always find the latest release by going to https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases/.

Try a manual install of the plugin manager:

1. Close `notepad++`
2. Download the latest plugin manager `PluginManager_1.4.9_UNI.zip` from https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases/download/v1.4.9/PluginManager_v1.4.9_UNI.zip
3. Unzip the downloaded file
4. Copy `plugins\PluginManager.dll` to your `notepad++\plugins` directory
5. Restart `notepad++`

Comment: I guess I found the underlying problem: I needed administrator privileges to copy the dll into the plugins directory. Now the PlugInManager is up-to-date. But even when I run Notepad++ as administrator, plugin installation still fails.

Comment: Have you tried (re)installing `notepad++` as an adminstrator?

Comment: Yes I have. I did so multiple times.

Comment: This resolved the issue for myself.

Comment: Note that this plugin manager is incompatible with the x64 version of N++

Comment: You can choose the download from https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases/ - it might be a good idea to put a path to choose the downloads, since the version mentioned in this answer is out of date.

Comment: @adpro Thanks. Added that link to the answer.

Comment: @ DavidPostill Answer updated in more general way.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and the solution was simple:

1. Go to Plugin Manager via `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager`
2. Click on the `Installed` tab
3. Check `Plugin Manager`
4. `Reinstall`

Notepad++ will auto restart after prompt and the issue will be gone.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this worked, but it worked for me, lol

Comment: Strange, I don't have Plugin Manager listed on the "installed" tab.

Answer (score 5):

Control panel -> Internet options -> Advanced
Scroll down to Security.
Make sure TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 are all checked.

Good luck!

Comment: Probably it's vice versa, I had all options checked and it was failing. So I *unchecked* 1.0 and 1.1 and now it's fine. See https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15472/installation-of-everything-failed/4

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me was to simply copy the ComparePlugin.dll file from another PC where the plugin was installed. The file location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem again (in current version 6.9) and found a workaround:

I just selected the "AutoSave" plugin as well. When I clicked "Install", it failed on AutoSave plugin installation, but Compare, being second, went through smoothly, and Compare plugin is usable now.

So, unless you want to install the first plugin the list, this workaround is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use the operating system win10 and my system type 64x.
Anyway I installed to x64 notepadd++ from notepad++ website.
But plugin manager has a trouble to install from "ProgramFiles".I removed at and I installed to 32-bit(x86).The trouble gone.
My advice is you install notepad++(x86) if your system x64 (64-bit).

Also ////

Included plugins:

1. NppExport v0.2.8 (32-bit x86 only)
2. Plugin Manager 1.3.5 (32-bit x86 only)
3. Converter 4.2
4. Mime Tool 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to update the plugin manager, as detailed by other answers, did not resolve the issue for me and the "Installation of Compare failed" persisted.
I was able to manually install the plugin, though.

- Download the source code from the [Github project](https://github.com/jsleroy/compare-plugin),
- use Visual Studio to build the project
- and copy the compiled artifacts into \Notepad++\plugins folder.