# Notepad++ Plugin Manager Update Infinite Loop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, notepad++, uac

When trying to install a plugin using the Notepad++ Plugin Manager on Windows 10 (this may happen on any Windows => 7), the update manager prompts to be updated before installing the update. I click Yes, then see a UAC prompt asking for admin access to update the program, Notepadd++ wants to be restarted to finish the update of Plugin Manager.

It seems like everything went fine, but when trying to install a plugin, the process just starts over. When checking the Plugin Manager version, it never changes, but there are no errors presented, either.

This is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1171168/notepad-plugin-manager-fails-update), however, in that case, Notepadd++ presented an error when updating, while in my case, there is no error, it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you see a UAC prompt asking to make changes to the program during the update of Plugin Manager, it does not allow Notepadd++ to make these changes to its files.
In order to successfully update the Plugin Manager, Notepadd++ must first be started as Administrator:

1. Find the Notepadd++ shortcut in the start menu
2. Right-click the shortcut, and select "Run As Administrator" or similar
3. Confirm the UAC prompt or enter admin password.
4. Proceed with the Plugin Manager Update